# Bind to multiple interface but not all/0.0.0.0 in UDP

Tags: netty

Hello I use netty 4 and I send UDP dgram from different source address, I first try with binding Bootstrap to a single port bind(0) and sending datagram with different sender, each sender being a source ip of one of my interface (eth0:0, eth0:1, ...). It didn't work, it was always sending from the same Interface. So I don't know if it's a bug, maybe the sender field of the datagram is only used for being able to know the sender in recv() but not to fix source in send().

Next I try by binding my bootstrap multiple time to all the interfaces I want to use :

```
foreach (ifaces as iface){
  channels.add(client.bind(iface).sync().channel());
}
```

But it triggered an exception. Is it impossible to call bind multiple time on a same bootsrap ?

So I finally succeeded by creating one bootstrap for each interface, something like :

```
foreach (ifaces as iface){
  client = new Bootstrap().group(reuseThePool).
     channel(NioDatagramChannel.class).handler(new Handler(this));
  channels.add(client.bind(iface).sync().channel());
}
```

And it works, but is it the way to go ? one bootstrap for each bind() ?